# Finding the closest value of median value in duplicated rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, median

I have a DataFrame which contains more than 2000 rows.

Here is a part of my DataFrame:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
     A    B     C     D
0    a    b    -1   3.5
1    a    b    -1    52
2    a    b    -1     2
3    a    b    -1     0
4    a    b     0    15
5    a    c    -1  1612
6    a    c     1    17
7    a    e     1    52
8    a    d    -1   412
9    a    d    -1   532
```

I would like to find the index of the closest (next) value of the median value of D column grouping by A, B and C and also add a new column as `Next_Med` to label it.

Here is the expected result :

```
     A    B     C     D   Next_Med
0    a    b    -1   3.5          1
1    a    b    -1    52          0
2    a    b    -1     2          0
3    a    b    -1     0          0
4    a    b     0    15          1
5    a    c    -1  1612          1
6    a    c     1    17          1
7    a    e     1    52          1
8    a    d    -1   412          0
9    a    d    -1   532          1
```

For example for a, b and -1 combination, the median value is 2.75 so I'd like to label 3.5 as `Next_Med`.

Comment: By `closest (next) value of the median value`, do you mean the closest value **larger than** the median? Or the closest value to the median in either direction?

Comment: The median for `a d  -1` is `472.00`  meaning both idx 8 and idx 9 are 60 away from the median. What should be done in case of equidistance (always choose the last occurance)?

Comment: Yes larger value, @PeterLeimbigler.

Comment: Not the last occurance, bigger occurance @HenryEcker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following one-liner with `groupby` and `tranform` with `lambda`:

```
>>> df['Next_Med'] = df.sort_values([*'ABC']).groupby([*'ABC'])['D'].transform(lambda x: x == min(x, key=lambda y: abs(y - x.median()))).astype(int).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
   A  B  C       D  Next_Med
0  a  b -1     3.5         1
1  a  b -1    52.0         0
2  a  b -1     2.0         0
3  a  b -1     0.0         0
4  a  b  0    15.0         1
5  a  c -1  1612.0         1
6  a  c  1    17.0         1
7  a  e  1    52.0         1
8  a  d -1   412.0         0
9  a  d -1   532.0         1
>>>
```

Comment: Cool solution! A minor point: @Hahuro confirmed they actually want to choose the closest value *larger than* the group median. I think this solution chooses the closest value on either side of the group median.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler exactly, it was the answer that I was looking for.